# How is transferFrom secure?

Tags: security

```
function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
    _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
    return true;
}
```

Transfer happens before approve. Or does the method fail and everything reverts back if anything in the method fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a transaction is reverted at any point in the transaction, the whole transaction is reverted. In this case, `.sub(amount)` will revert if `amount` is larger than the allowance, so the token transfer will be reverted as well in that case.